# TypeScript: type narrowing is lost when moving to generics

Tags: typescript

See this example, I would like to understand why Test1 fails while Test2 succeeds, and if there is any way to make Test1 pass without removing the generic signature:

```
enum TableType {
    Shipment = "Shipment",
    Batch = "Batch",
}

type Test<T extends TableType> = T extends TableType.Shipment
    ? number
    : string

function test1<T extends TableType>(source: T) {
    if (source === TableType.Shipment) {
        type Test1 = Test<typeof source> // type is T extends TableType.Shipment ? number : string
        const ret: Test1 = 0 // fail (unexpected)
        const ret1: Test1 = "" // fail (expected)
    }
}

function test2(source: TableType) {
    if (source === TableType.Shipment) {
        type Test2 = Test<typeof source> // type is number
        const ret: Test2 = 0 // pass (expected)
        const ret1: Test2 = "" // fail (expected)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKghgIwDbBgTwA7CgbwFBSFQDKAFgJYYSgAuUAvFAERmXUg1MA0BRAQnBoBjUg2YDhpbngC+ePDUzYYwAM40APDCjAAHjVAATVbEQp0WAHxjtegyGOnkqJQDpWVWr0IB+KOAgEYAAnbygALih1YPIQAHN5ADMwECEacgB7ECgDdQBGLR19IxN4ZwtgSwAKVQywYKFgSJgASlww8kSoGrqG7HoBp3M3D3YaNvwiKZylWDUaPJt5jUUsDK7a+sbLMKmhLPUoYOAaZvnFxgAGKAB6G6gAQhS9LDTgQx1g4IzQ6aJ9kCHY4LM75MRMJhhORyPDJVLpLI5eYAJh6WyaQxcWAmHS6aL6DEGZWGWHcFE8HBxf0Iq2UKKW6hWSnWUV6212-wOdGBoJoyLElw5hABQJOeV5-MYEKhsjwQA)

Comment: control flow anlaysis and generics don't play well. See [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [ms/TS#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912). This might be implemented sometime soon, but if not, you can't change it without refactoring to something non-generic like you have, or something generic like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ3xrw). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes you are right, thanks for showing me, I got the wrong issue in my answer below. Thank you!!

Comment: @jcalz Just to let you know your solution worked like an absolute charm on the code I derived this simplified example from, super grateful, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found this is being tracked in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014

edit: thanks to @jcalz's comment for correcting me on the issue number 33014

Comment: No, that's not the right issue for this (although I too thought that a while ago).  The correct issues here are ms/TS#33014 and ms/TS#33912. See my comment above and let me know if you want me to write up an answer.